# CUDA profiling tools "no kernels were profiled"

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvidia

I can't get CUDA profiling tools from being working. My laptop Asus has two video cards. One integrated (Intel) and another one, Nvidia GTX 960M.

I suspected that the visual profiler is using the integrated video card, so I changed the default video card for this specific application, under the “Nvidia Control Panel” and “Manager 3d Settings->Program Settings” to use the “High-Performance NVidia Processor”.

Nothing changed. Running the Visual Profiler, in the “Overall GPU usage” tab, I get “No GPU devices in Session”, which means I far as I can understand that no GPU’s were used.

Also, I noticed that the Nvidia display icon in the notification area is not reporting any applications that are using the video card.

What seems to be the problem here? How can I enable also the Nvidia GPU for both Visual Profiler and the command line nvprof.exe application? It seems neither Nsight works for me.

The code I am testing is the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


#define NUM_THREADS 256

#define IMG_SIZE 1048576

struct Coefficients_SOA {
  int r;
  int b;
  int g;
  int hue;
  int saturation;
  int maxVal;
  int minVal;
  int finalVal; 
};


__global__
void complicatedCalculation(Coefficients_SOA*  data)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


  int grayscale = (data[i].r + data[i].g + data[i].b)/data[i].maxVal;
  int hue_sat = data[i].hue * data[i].saturation / data[i].minVal;
  data[i].finalVal = grayscale*hue_sat; 
}

void complicatedCalculation()
{

  Coefficients_SOA* d_x;

  cudaMalloc(&d_x, IMG_SIZE*sizeof(Coefficients_SOA)); 

  int num_blocks = IMG_SIZE/NUM_THREADS;

  complicatedCalculation<<<num_blocks,NUM_THREADS>>>(d_x);

  cudaFree(d_x);
}



int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    complicatedCalculation();
    return 0;
}
```

Best Regards,

PS: I installed CUDA Version 11 under win10/64bit

[image]

[image]

Also, I verified the CUDA installation according to https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Windows.pdf

I attach the DeviceQuery and BandwidthTest CUDA sample programs for your convenience.

### deviceQuery Sample report

```
    D:\Program Files\nVidia\CUDA Samples\v11.0\bin\win64\Release>deviceQuery
deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 960M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          11.0 / 11.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294967296 bytes)
  ( 5) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     640 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1176 MHz (1.18 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 4 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Managed Memory:                Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 11.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 11.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

### BandwidthTest Sample report

```
D:\Program Files\nVidia\CUDA Samples\v11.0\bin\win64\Release>bandwidthTest
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
Running on...

 Device 0: GeForce GTX 960M
 Quick Mode

 Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(GB/s)
   32000000                     12.2

 Device to Host Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(GB/s)
   32000000                     11.8

 Device to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(GB/s)
   32000000                     68.9

Result = PASS

NOTE: The CUDA Samples are not meant for performance measurements. Results may vary when GPU Boost is enabled.
```

Comment: You'll need to make sure that: 1. You don't have any `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable set.  2. Your application  and laptop have the GTX960M actually enabled/powered on.  You may wish to read [this](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2615/~/how-do-i-customize-optimus-profiles-and-settings%3F).  3.  You have properly enabled profiling as described [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM-permission-issue-performance-counters).

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks, I will check them all and I  will let you know.

Comment: @RobertCrovella In my environment variable, there is no `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I can confirm that I fulfilled all 3 sections you mentioned but I didn't see any difference. Using  Visual Profiler or CLI nvprof I can also confirm that Nvidia GPU activity in the notification area, does not report both of the applications above.

Comment: did you [verify your CUDA install](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#verify-installation) ?  Have you confirmed that you can run compiled CUDA codes correctly?  And, the GTX960M is a cc5.0 device that is not supported by nsight compute/nsight systems, so you should focus your attention on `nvvp` (or `nvprof`)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, Robert. I edited the initial post to include the DeviceQuery and BandwidthTest Samples that seems to run just fine. And yes, I read that Maxwell architect that is my GTX960M, is not supported by nsight.

Comment: Running other samples from the CUDA SDK, I can verify that `nvprof` reports correctly the `GPU Device 0: "Maxwell" with compute capability 5.0` implication. As far as I can understand by this, the CUDA code I am testing with (attached in later edition of the initial post),  does not implicate any GPU work, that's why I get `No kernels were. profiled.`. Do you think that my assumption is correct?

Comment: This seems to be a moving target now.  Initially you were reporting a "No GPU" error message.  Now you are asking about "No kernels were profiled".  Anyway when I run the code you have now posted, it seems to run without error and is certainly generating GPU activity.  When I profile with `nvprof`, I see the kernel launch, for example.  One thing I would suggest is adding `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before the end of your program, and another possibility is you are compiling incorrectly.  CUDA 11.0 compiles for cc5.2 by default, but your GPU is cc5.0.  You should use proper CUDA error checking.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes visual profiler as you can see in the image reports no gpu but nvprof reports no kernels were profiled. Running the attached code with nvprof in your system, does it returns the same warning?

Comment: No it doesn't.  I already indicated "When I profile with nvprof, I see the kernel launch, for example. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. As a beginner in the CUDA world, I didn't know that I should add the parameter *gencode* to compile my CUDA files under the command line (Visual Studio of CUDA SDK sample projects are already had these parameters that's why I had GPU activity).

So, the full parameter list under the command line should be like this for my maxwell architecture with CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number 5.0.

```
nvcc -run -m64 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -o aos_soa.exe aos_soa.cu
```

Unfortunately, my 1st book "*Learn CUDA Programming*", from Packt Publishing, on page 49 refers that I should compile ONLY with the following parameters, besides the fact that in the source code files is contains a "Makefile" that includes all of the parameters above (only for linux, so I ignored it).

```
$ nvcc -o aos_soa ./aos_soa.cu
```

Now I can see my GPU statistics under **nvprof**.

```
nvprof aos_soa.exe
==18308== NVPROF is profiling process 18308, command: aos_soa.exe
==18308== Profiling application: aos_soa.exe
==18308== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:  100.00%  1.1421ms         1  1.1421ms  1.1421ms  1.1421ms  complicatedCalculation(Coefficients_SOA*)
      API calls:   83.40%  226.57ms         1  226.57ms  226.57ms  226.57ms  cudaMalloc
                   15.90%  43.183ms         1  43.183ms  43.183ms  43.183ms  cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease
                    0.58%  1.5790ms         1  1.5790ms  1.5790ms  1.5790ms  cudaFree
                    0.07%  198.40us         1  198.40us  198.40us  198.40us  cuModuleUnload
                    0.03%  70.100us         1  70.100us  70.100us  70.100us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  26.800us         1  26.800us  26.800us  26.800us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.01%  20.200us       101     200ns     100ns  3.3000us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.00%  11.600us         1  11.600us  11.600us  11.600us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  1.4000us         3     466ns     200ns     700ns  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  1.4000us         2     700ns     200ns  1.2000us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     600ns         1     600ns     600ns     600ns  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%     400ns         1     400ns     400ns     400ns  cuDeviceGetLuid
                    0.00%     300ns         1     300ns     300ns     300ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
```